# A rhyming riddle made by me, is not as good as Riley's can be

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.
I have a tail, a tail I can bend.
My infix in every circle you find.
So tell me, have you made up  your mind?

Hint 1:

> To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape,

Hint 2:

> The last line is not a hint. I've added that line just to have a rhyme to the previous one.

Hint 3:

> After a long period of time,
>  you've lost your tail, but I kept mine.

EDIT: Sorry for the big mistake... I accidentally put prefix und suffix in the wrong order of the riddle. I apologize for that.

Comment: the hint looks like something was cut off. Is that the whole hint or are you planning on adding more to it later?

Comment: This is the first hint. I can add up more if needed.

Comment: yes please I have tried many ideas but can't solve it :)

Comment: oh shooot I realized I made a huge mistake in my riddle. I accidentally put suffix and prefix in the wrong place...

Comment: aaaaaaaah now that changes things xD my best guess for that line was that they are the same ^^

Comment: I'm so sorry for confusing you with that stupid mistake

Comment: how many letters in the word?

Comment: If I tell you this, you would immediately know the answer ;)

Comment: @D3f4u1t is the first hint meant to have a second line as well (as part of the poem), or is it standalone?

Comment: it's a standalone, since I wasn't able to create a fitting rhyme to it

Comment: How is the first line a hint? Isn't that true for all riley puzzles?

Comment: You have to take that line more literally

Comment: @D3f4u1t is there another hint available for this riddle? :)

Comment: Hey @D3f4u1t, not related to the question, but have you ever played a game called "Hacknet"?

Comment: Is it an animal we seek?

Comment: @PerpetualJ Yes it's actually an animal

Comment: @Cubemaster Yes, I 've also played several expansions, too

Comment: @D3f4u1t fingers crossed on my latest guess! It's too bad that we're starting to guess again now that the bounty is over, but I just want to see this solved! ;P

Comment: Can we expect a new hint now that the bounty is gone? I am really looking forward to the answer for this one.

Comment: @D3f4u1t I only ask about the game because your name is the same as one in the expansion. Is that where you got the name?

Comment: @Cubemaster I got the name from Watchdog from a character named D3fr4g

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This go is a naked copy:

> ape - suggested by iiiidk.

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.

> A is the first letter of the alphabet. E is in the word end  - PerpetualJ's deduction.

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Apes have a bendy, prehensile tail.

My infix in every circle you find.

> For the circle constant, before embracing the symbol π, an abbreviation of the Greek word for *p*eriphery, mathematicians used letters like p instead. P is also in pi.

Title & Hints: A rhyming riddle made by me, is not as good as Riley's can be

> An ape of the genre popularised by Riley. It's on tape and humans only have vestigial coccyx.

Comment: if this is a copy, from whom?

Comment: @D3f4u1t - I was using copy as a play on words as it's a synonym of this answer, and the form of the question mimic's a Riley which - a thought is - clued in your title. Also my answer was mentioned as the last animal of iiiidk's [post](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70398/19547) and uses the tail 'e' of PerpetualJ's [solution](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/a/70398/19547).

Comment: Well, kudos to you... your answer is right :)

Comment: Thanks @D3f4u1t - you reduced the Riley format to a minimum. Neat!

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer could be:

> SPINE

My suffix comes first:

> "S" often comes at the end of words

My prefix in the end:

> "NE" Prefix prepended to adjectives to create an adjective denoting a negative meaning

I have a tail, a tail I can bend:

> The spine has a slight bend to it and can bend in many directions

My infix in every circle you find:

> "PI" is in every circle

Have you made up your mind:

> The mind (or brain) is "up" at the top of your spine

Comment: your explanation for line 3 is correct, but your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 4):

Is it:

> Ape

My prefix comes first

> 'A' being the first letter in the alphabet

my suffix in the end

> E is in 'the end'

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Stretching it here, as apes don't have proper tails. Unless you include the tailbone, which for those unfortunate enough, can be bent.

My infix in every circle you find.

> Read as "My infix in every ,circle you find.", e.g. "you'll find a circle in every one of my infixes".  Could be the loop in the letter 'p'

To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape,

> 'Ape' in the word tape

Comment: This has absolutely got to be it.. OP?

Comment: @D3f4u1t, was my explanation on the tail where I missed here?

Answer (score 3):

Are you a

> Scorpion

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.

> Literally speaking, they do.

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Check.

My infix in every circle you find.

> PI

As for the hint

> [Scorpion barrier tape](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0053TOX88) is used to catch scorpions

Comment: nice shot but wrong. I've added another hint

Answer (score 3):

I know this is probably wrong; but it's worth a shot.

Are you a:

> Mouse

*My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.*

> Based on literal thinking, the **M** comes first in this sentence; **E** is *in* the **end**.

*I have a tail, a tail I can bend.*

> Mice definitely have tails, and they can whip them around quite quickly too.

*My infix in every circle you find.*

> Everyone is relating this to **pi**; however, I have been thinking in a more literal aspect, for example: if you break down a circle, it has a circumference, a diameter, and a radius. Taking this into account, the **u** in mouse is present in *circumference* and *radius*; the **s** is found in *radius*, and I couldn't find a relation for the **o**.

**Hint 1**:

> You can certainly catch mice on special tape.

**Hint 3**:

> Mice never lost their tails through evolution.

I will be making another attempt at this if I'm wrong. Also, if wrong; can the OP clarify the following?

> You've already stated we are looking for an animal. Are we looking for the scientific name or common name?

Comment: that's the best guess so far, I'm looking for the common name of an animal. I will try to provide another link during the day :)

Comment: This was a great answer!! +1 from me

Comment: Regarding the infix part, (ROT13) “B” fuBhyq or gur zBfg BoivBhf Bar; vg yBBxf yvxr n  pvepyr! $(+1)$, though :D

Comment: Well I could agree but my brain was definitely not in literal mode at that time. I'll keep working this, I'm a big fan of animals so animal riddles are always going to grab my attention!

Answer (score 3):

I've got a guess for this, and it's 100% based on @PerpetualJ's answer, so please go upvote their answer!! That said, are you

> A [MAGPIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-billed_magpie)?

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.

> As @PerpetualJ mentioned, the prefix coming first refers to M coming first; the suffix in the end refers to E being in "the end".

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Magpies have extremely long, somewhat flexible tails for birds.

My infix in every circle you find.

> As @D3f4u1t has mentioned, this infix is PI.

So tell me, have you made up your mind?

> I hope so - an animal M...PI..E can only be a few things, if I have the interpretations correct.

Hint 1:

> To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape, 
>  **This could refer to [*Magpie Tape*, a form of industrial tape](https://www.industrysearch.com.au/masking-tape-magpie/p/85468)**.

Hint 3:

> After a long period of time, 
>  you've lost your tail, but I kept mine. 
>  **Humans lost their tails thousands of years ago, but magpies still have tails.**

Comment: Perhaps, (ROT13) gur cersvk cneg zvtug ersre gb “zn” nf va “zbgure”. Lbhe zbgure pbzrf svefg orsber lbh qb. $(+1)$, though :D

Answer (score 2):

Probably not right, but my best bet is a

> Spider Monkey

My suffix comes first, my prefix in the end.

> No idea

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Spider Monkeys have prehensile tails

My infix in every circle you find.

> pi

So tell me, have you made up your mind?

> Not really, but I am trying.

Comment: your answer is by far the most creative one :)

Comment: *"Have you made up your mind?"* Hmmm... aha! Yes! **N FCVQRE ZBAXRL!** :D

Comment: Yeah, these hints just seem to reinforce this. Definitely seems like a monkey of some sort

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> Protoplast?

My prefix comes first

> Proto meaning first or original

my suffix in the end

> last

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Possibly referring to chromosomes and mitosis.

My infix in every circle you find.

> Here's where things get dicey. It's already been confirmed that this is pi. However, protoplasm only has a p in the middle.

So tell me, have you made up your mind?

> Maybe referring to what gender a baby will be in pregnancy?

To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape,

> In old films, you can see some blotches on film that look a lot like protoplasm.

Comment: I think yours fits very well. My answer's guess for the infix *might* be helpful given your word.

Answer (score 1):

This might be a stretch but...

> An epidural?

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.

> Not really sure...

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> An epidural is an injection into the epidural space of the spine. Similar to what @zeethreepio said about the spine being a tail that can bend.

My infix in every circle you find.

> Pi

So tell me, have you made up your mind?

> Some women choose to have an epidural during labour, others choose not to.

Hint 1

> Epidural tape

Comment: Sorry this one is wrong

Comment: Regarding the second line, (ROT13) Gur cersvk “rcvq” pbhyq ersre gb “rcvqraqehz” juvpu vf gur trahf bs n pregnva glcr bs bepuvqf (xabja nf rcvyulgvp beqpuvqf, gung bs juvpu ner cnegvphyneyl sbhaq va Nzrevpn’f gebcvpny ertvbaf). Jura tvivat fpvragvsvp anzrf, gur trahf anzr pbzrf svefg, naq gur fcrpvrf anzr pbzrf frpbaq; v.r., TRAHF FCRPVRF. Fb guvf zvtug rkcynva ubj gur cersvk pbzrf svefg? $(+1)$, though :D

Answer (score 1):

> thoughts: magpie, tapir, porcupine, wapiti, treepie, spider, sandpiper. 
> Ignoring scientific names for creatures.
> Out of these, the easiest for me to fit are: magpie, treepie

Explanation for:

> [treepie](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treepie)

My prefix comes first, my suffix in the end.

> trees were one of the first, and the creation of oxygen let us come to be. "e" is in "the end".

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> treepies have long tails, and when birbs clean their tail feathers they tend to bend them, [kind of like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yz-EFTT9A8Y).

My infix in every circle you find.

> as confirmed above, "pi"

To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape,

> animal or cryptid

After a long period of time,
you've lost your tail, but I kept mine.

> any animal with a tail, but this seems to hint something similar to a human, i.e. in the realm of ape. A birb is certainly not an ape, but it has a tail :^)

Answer (score 1):

Could you be a

> Porcupine?

My prefix comes first,

> Many people eat bacon (pork) for breakfast

my suffix in the end.

> NE, New England is the most superior region of the USA and will certainly survive the longest in the zombie apocalypse

I have a tail, a tail I can bend.

> Many porcupines have prehensile tails

My infix in every circle you find.

> Pretty sure this is "pi"

Hint 1:

To provide you a hint, you can catch me on tape,

> Animal Planet FTW

Hint 2:

The last line is not a hint. I've added that line just to have a rhyme to the previous one.

> Okay then

Hint 3:

After a long period of time,
you've lost your tail, but I kept mine.

> Humans don't have tails, porcupines do.

Comment: That third line, hahah! $(+1)$ :P